# How can I find the Right curly brace corresponding to left curly brace in a string by regular expression？

Tags: regex

The string is like below：

```
abcd lookatme:{b:{d:'asdf'},c:{f:'asdfasdfasdf'} },nooooooo:{b:{d:'asdf'},c:{} },
```

I want to find the "}" corresponding to "{" behind the 'lookatme'.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An interesting alternative to capturing **only** the matching closing
brace is a regex to match the **whole** substring:

- from the opening, top-level brace,
- including the content,
- up to (including) the paired closing brace.

To match such a substring, use the following regex

```
(\{(?:[^{}]*(?R))*[^{}]*\})
```

Details:

- `(` - Start of a capturing group.
- `\{` - Opening brace (represents itself).
- `(?:` - Start of the inner, non-capturing group.

  - `[^{}]*` - Any number of chars other than both braces.
  - `(?R)` - Recursive invocation to the whole pattern.
- `)*` - End of the inner, non-capturing group. This group can occur *0* times or more.
- `\}` - Closing brace (represents itself).
- `[^{}]*` - Any number of chars other than both braces.
- `)` - End of a capturing group.

This way you match each top-level pair of braces.
The closing brace, paired with the opening brace (what you actually want
to match) is the **last** char of the current match.

For a working example see: https://regex101.com/r/5gESHI/1

The source text includes:

- 2 top-level brace groups with 2 nested groups (as in your source sample),
- another top-level brace group with no nested brace group,
- yet another top-level brace group with a single nested brace group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to use it in javascript,what should i do to make it work in ecmascript?

Comment: I'm afraid that JavaScript flavour of regex does not support *(?R)* (resursive patterns). Maybe you should do it another way, using your own piece of JavaScript code?